# Parser combinators info

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I am using parsing combinators in scala
If I have recursive parser:

```
val uninterestingthings = ".".r

val parser = "(?ui)(regexvalue)".r | (uninterestingthings~>parser)
```

How can I check how many characters of input my parser consumed?

Comment: Doesn't look recursive to me.  Is it a typo? (s/parser2/parser/)

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. Now it looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `positioned` combinator that (to quote its documentation) "decorates a parser's result with the start position of the input it consumed."